# Nhibernate uses a lot of memory

Tags: asp.net, fluent-nhibernate, memory-leaks

I've got fluent nhibernate in my application and I'm trying to locate the cause of high memory usage.  (I say high, it's 60MB, but it's a web app and it's not very big) Unfortunately it looks like a lot of it is in unmanaged memory, so I started taking things out - and as soon as I took out any calls to nhibernate, the memory usage dropped to 11MB!!  Why oh why would it be taking up so much memory?  Especially, why would it be taking up unmanaged memory?

I've been 'Googling' this all day and all I can find are posts from people saying "NHibernate eats memory..." and answers that say "no it doesn't, there's no evidence".  Are NHibernate people in denial about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible reasons: NHibernate caching.

Check these articles:

- http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/24/nhibernate-2nd-level-cache.aspx
- http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/quickly-setting-up-and-using-nhibernate-s-second-level-cache.aspx

Keep in mind "more memory usage" shouldn't be "this is devil". I mean that some caching or other factors would increase overall performance if the machine hosting everything has enough resources.

You can use this free profiler too, so you can check what's "wasting" your memory - maybe it's not a waste of memory but a proper usage for performance optimization - :

- http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/

Comment: Thanks - to some extend the caching is happening as I can see a lot of my data objects just hanging around (which I'm not 100% happy about, but it's only really about 4MB, but I'd rather it wasn't there as for the larger sites i've got it's using about 70MB so i will look at trying to turn that off) - it's the unmanaged memory allocation at 30MB that I'm worried about the most...it seems like a lot.

Comment: Oh, i have a trial version of ANTS at the moment, which seems to be very good so may stick with this for the time being.

Comment: Well, I suggested you a free profiler for the case of not having a one already :) Hmmm, what unmanaged memory leak can be a problem of NHibernate if this is fully-managed? Very strange.

Comment: I know, it's really odd - but that's the ooonly thing I enable, just open and close a session, and wallop - 30MB unmanaged. gah

Comment: And are you disposing such session?

Comment: Have you tried to download NHib source code, compile yourself and debug its code so you can find where's that memory leak?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not convinced it's in nhib, I think there's probably a configuration issues.  I've disabled the 2nd level cache for now, but the objects are still being held in memory (yet not accessed as the cache is disabled).  They appear to be referenced by "NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext"